# How does an electron actually act when struck by an photon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I know that the planetary model of an electron orbiting the nucleus is not a good way to envision it. Rather, the electron should be viewed as a cloud surrounding the nucleus.

1. When a photon is aimed at an atom, does the photon need to actually strike the electron exactly where it is (which would be a very small point somewhere around the nucleus) or can the photon strike anywhere in the cloud?
2. We are told that when a photon strikes an electron, it lifts it to a higher orbit.  Does it actually increase the diameter of the cloud?  Or is it more accurate to say that it just increases the energy with which the electron is orbiting the nucleus?
3. We are told that when the electron strikes the electron, it lifts it to a higher orbit, but then the electron falls back down again and emits a new photon.  How fast does this happen?  And does the new photon exit in a random direction or in the same direction as the original photon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In photon -atom interactions it is not the electron that is hit, it is an interaction of the whole atom.

If the photon has the energy difference to change [the orbital](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) ( probabiity locus, not an orbit) of the electron to a higher energy level, it is absorbed, by the whole atom.

The relaxation of the electron to a lower orbital by emission of a photon will depend on the specific atom, and the time will depend on the width [of the line in the spectrum.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Atomic/broaden.html)

The direction of the de-excitation photon will depend on the quantum numbers of the two energy levels but will be random with respect to the original.

Comment: "If the photon has the energy difference to change the orbital ( probabiity locus, not an orbit) of the electron to a higher energy level, it is absorbed, by the whole atom."  So there is NO change to the size or shape of the atom, it just has more energy?       How fast would the relaxation be for a hydrogen atom?

Comment: I think I gave a link for the relaxation .  The size and shape of an atom is determined by the extension of the orbitals, i.e. how far from the center of mass the scattering with the atom will happen. there is a lin for that too. It is all in probability space at the quantum mechanical level of atoms and molecules, sizes and all.( including  relaxation time). One has to do many scatterings with the same conditions and take the lifetime  and form from the plots.

Comment: Really nice answer.